# Update query with two different where conditions

Tags: postgresql, update

I would like to set `status` to `false` for all rows except one, which should should be set to `true`. How can I achieve that?

Here is the query I tried:

```
UPDATE students set status = false where status = true and 
set status = true where _id = 1;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a case expression:

```
UPDATE students 
    set status = CASE WHEN _ID = 1 THEN true
                                   ELSE false
                 END;
```

A bit shorter (but perhaps not as obvious) is:

```
UPDATE students 
    set status = COALESCE(_ID = 1,false);
```

COALESCE is need if _ID can be NULL.

One may argue that it is not necessary to update status at all times (for efficiency reasons). If we take into consideration that both _ID and status can be null there are 9 different situations (we let _ID = 0 represent all rows where _ID is not null and _ID <> 1).

```
_ID    Status    Action
-----------------------
null   null      set false
null   true      set false
null   false     -
   0   null      set false
   0   true      set false
   0   false     -
   1   null      set true
   1   true      - 
   1   false     set true
```

All Actions is handled by:

```
set status = COALESCE(_ID = 1,false);
```

So we need to filter out the 3 situations where no update should take place:

```
(null, false), (0, false), (1, true)
```

In other words, our `WHERE` clause should include the other 6 combinations:

```
UPDATE students 
    set status = COALESCE(_id = 1,false)
WHERE ((coalesce(_id, 0) = 1) <> coalesce(status,(coalesce(_id, 0) <> 1)))
```

This is not trivial (IMO), and even though it probably can be simplified I would not recommend to use it in any real situation (I would recommend disallowing nulls for boolean attributes in the first place, but that's another story).

A useful technique (once again IMO) to verify boolean expressions with truth tableau's, is to use CTE's for the domains and investigate the result. Example from above:

```
with status (s) as ( values (null),(false),(true))
  ,     _id (i) as ( values (null),(0),(1))
select i, s from status cross join _id
where ((coalesce(i, 0) = 1) <> coalesce(s,(coalesce(i, 0) <> 1)));
```

`IS DISTINCT FROM` as demonstrated by @Erwin Brandstetter is a nice abstraction that is very useful in situations like these.

Comment: thank you, this is was exactly i was looking for but i failed to explain, i will improve myself to ask questions in a proper way!! thanks again;)

Comment: The 1st query works for NULL values, too (though possibly also updating rows that don't need it). The 2nd and 3rd variants would fail. `(_ID = 1)` is not fully equivalent to the `CASE` expression  because it returns NULL for NULL input while the `CASE` expression (correctly) returns `false`. And `<>` also fails with NULL values.

Comment: True, updated answer

Comment: `status <> COALESCE(_ID = 1,false)` still fails with NULL in `status`.

Comment: Now, `COALESCE(status,false) <> COALESCE(_ID = 1,false)` would not update rows with `status IS NULL` that should be `false` ...

Comment: Hopefully I got it right this time, time is a precious gift for the moment

Comment: @Schüler: Illustrates the value of a table definition in the question, showing data types and constraints. Else, speculation and (silent) assumptions create noise and confusion.

Answer (score 2):

While `status` and `_id` can be NULL (and neither is defined `NOT NULL` in the question) you *have to* consider NULL values. You can use [`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE):

```
UPDATE students 
SET    status = (_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 1)
WHERE  status IS DISTINCT FROM (_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 1);
```

Equivalent in this case:

```
UPDATE students 
SET    status = CASE WHEN _id = 1 THEN true ELSE false END
WHERE  status IS DISTINCT FROM (CASE WHEN _id = 1 THEN true ELSE false END);
```

That's assuming a `UNIQUE` constraint on `_id`. (As Lennart pointed out in a comment.)

Related:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Comment: All rows with _id = 1 will be `true` contrary to `I would like to set status to false for all rows except one` ;-)

Comment: Also true. I was silently assuming a `UNIQUE` constraint on `_id` (like the OP seems to do in his pseudo-code). But just silently assuming is a loaded footgun in SQL.