# Make two different updates with two different where conditions

Tags: mariadb, update

Although [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203830/update-query-with-two-different-where-conditions) question is very similar, I don't think that it is also the best approach for my case, though it seemed to work. Consider the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
  writer VARCHAR(5),
  recipient VARCHAR(5),
  show_for_writer TINYINT(1), -- 0 for hidden, 1 for display
  show_for_recipient TINYINT(1) -- idem
);
```

I now want to create ONE update query which hides all messages of user `x` for him; i.e. which sets `show_for_writer` equal to 0 where the `writer` is `x`, AND which sets `show_for_recipient` equal to 0 where the `recipient` is `x`. Note that I want to make this as efficiently as possible, as this table may contain millions of records (one per message) for countless writer-recipient combinations (composite, non-unique index).

What I've tried to make, according to the linked post, is:

```
UPDATE messages
SET show_for_writer =
    CASE
    WHEN writer = 'x'
    THEN 0
    ELSE show_for_writer -- or even better, do nothing; only update if necessary
    END
    ,
    show_for_recipient =
    CASE WHEN recipient = 'x'
    THEN 0
    ELSE display_receiver -- or even better, do nothing; only update if necessary
    END
WHERE writer = 'x' OR recipient = 'x';
```

I however feel that this is not ideal AT ALL, because it goes through all the records of the table, and this query may not be done at a regular scale, but not rarely either. What's the best solution for this? I'm open for any solution, even structural column modification propositions; I'm using MariaDB 10.3.

An Idea I had was maybe to edit the structure as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
 participants VARCHAR(10) FULLTEXT,
 writer VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
 recipient VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
 show JSON NOT NULL
);
```

And do something like:

```
UPDATE messages
SET show = JSON_REPLACE(messages,'$.x',0)
WHERE MATCH(participants) AGAINST('x');
```

The problem here is that I query messages if they shall be shown for 'x' upon init. Hence, setting `show` to a `JSON` data type won't make it possible to index this column, hence to query in f(`show`) efficiently. That's why I thought this idea may not be ideal, but just to show you that I'm basically open even to modifications at the structural level.

Otherwise I could simply fire two subsequent `UPDATE` statements, like so:

```
UPDATE messages
SET show_for_writer = 0
WHERE writer = 'x';

UPDATE messages
SET show_for_recipient = 0
WHERE recipient = 'x';
```

But I really prefer to stick to using one query per action. Help please!

Check the example here, with the update query to be otpimized to avoid going over all records of the table:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6830d/1

Comment: can you please make a [mre], so that your question becomes clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do two `UPDATEs`.

And have a `PRIMARY KEY`

And two secondary indexes:

```
INDEX(recipient),
INDEX(writer)
```

If you are concerned about ACIT integrity, make a transaction:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE ... WHERE writer...
UPDATE ... WHERE recipient...
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Cheers buddy, this stuff is new to me! As I read from the internet, most sources use PDO to code transactions in PHP, though I used procedural mysqli for all other queries of my app so far. What do you recommend? Info about procedural mysqli transactions via PHP is limited, so I wouldn't mind using PDO for transactions in my app, yet I wonder if it's a good idea to use different APIs for database queries in the same app. What's your opinion on that, if I may ask?

Comment: @DevelJoe - No, do not mix PDO and mysqli in the same connection; they are separate APIs.  Each can do 'everything', though with significantly different syntax.  Mysqli procedural interface is the "same" as its object interface.

Comment: Nono, I meant using PDO whenever I make transactional queries (via a given connection, nothing to do with other queries), and procedural mysqli for simpler other queries (via a given other connection, nothing to do with other queries). By no means I would mix these APIs across a same connection. Guess it's still better to stick to procedural mysqli for everything? Just thought of using PDO because it seems to be much more popular as procedural mysqli for DB transactions via PHP.

Comment: PDO vs mysqli -- a religious debate that I stay out of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what's wrong with using this syntax?

```
UPDATE messages
SET show_for_writer =
    CASE
    WHEN writer = 'x'
    THEN 0
    ELSE show_for_writer -- or even better, do nothing; only update if necessary
    END
    ,
    show_for_recipient =
    CASE WHEN recipient = 'x'
    THEN 0
    ELSE display_receiver -- or even better, do nothing; only update if necessary
    END
WHERE writer = 'x' OR recipient = 'x';
```

No matter what solution you choose, every record will need to be checked for if the `writer` or `recipient` is the provided value, from a query standpoint.

Having proper indexing on those fields is how you ensure the most efficient UPDATE via index seek operations that only seek the values of your WHERE clause from a B-Tree (and therefore reduces how many data points need to be analyzed to find the records that need to be updated).

Comment: Yes exactly but the query above does not use the btree indexes, try it with my sample data and EXPLAIN UPDATE. That's actually my problem

Comment: @DevelJoe Ah ok that's what you should've asked lol, but yes that's because you're using an OR statement and trying to update two different fields, it's not possible for one index to cover your entire WHERE clause with OR. So you'd have to break up your query into two separate queries (and have two indexes, one for writer and one for recipient). This is the trade-off of performance for convenience. It's not a bad thing to have two queries though, an infact as just mentioned a good thing for performance since you can maximize leveraging indexing and minimize how many data points are analyzed.